# log4j ,,,cxf ,JSF (com.faces) logs not going to File

Tags: java, jsf-2, log4j, weblogic-10.x

We are using JSF2 ,Apache CXF2.5.2 deployed to weblogic10.3
We have log4j.properties defined with FileAppender to log messages to file.

```
  log4j.rootCategory=INFO, FA
```

All the log messages are going to log files ,except the messages from CXF(logininterceptor) web service soap requests logs and some of javax.faces exception goes to the CONSOLE(Adminserver.log).

So rootcategory is not working for cxf logs and javax.faces ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CXF does not use Log4j by default.

Did you check [this](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html#DebuggingandLogging-UsingLog4jInsteadofjava.util.logging) ?